# How to make a AI system that chooses fastest way and navigates through walls to a certain grid spot

Tags: java, algorithm

Basically I'm trying to improve on the Ghosts in a Pacman game I'm making. In the orginal pacman when a Ghost is eaten when Pacman has picked up the Power the Ghosts eyes would navigate back to the home area and then spawn the ghost back in. I would like to do this to. It would also help me with implementing a Ghost AI to make them move smarter then just random.

So basically those eyes would have to navigate through this:

[image: pacman area]

And the board is being drawn from the below 2D array:

```
  //0's = Walls or location not allowed to go
  //1's = Dot Spot
  //2's = Clear Path nothing on it but safe to move
  //3's = Power Dot
  //-1's = only ghosts can go through
  //5= Top entry spot
  //6= bottom entry point
  //7 = Cherry
  //(Spots = row - 1 same with columns = - 1. First # is row. Second is col
  public int board[][] =
  {{2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, //1
    {2, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0, 2}, //2
    {2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2}, //3
    {2,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,2}, //4
    {2,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,2}, //5
    {2,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,2}, //6
    {2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,2}, //7
    {2,2,2,2,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,2,2,2,2}, //8
    {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,-1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0}, //9
    {5,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,0,2,2,2,0, 1 ,1,1,2,2,2,2,6}, //10 - cherry
    {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0}, //11
    {2,2,2,2,0,1,0,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,0,1,0,2,2,2,2}, //12
    {2,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,2}, //13
    {2,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,2}, //14 - pacman on this row
    {2,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,2}, //15
    {2,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,2}, //16 
    {2,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,2}, //17
    {2,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,2}, //18
    {2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,2}, //19
    {2,0,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,0,2}, //20
    {2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2}}; //21
```

So my question is how should I go about making the eyes go to the centre home spot in the fastest way without going through walls?

Comment: @sje397 don't be evil :) Dijkstra will do just fine on this map.

Comment: See http://gameinternals.com/post/2072558330/understanding-pac-man-ghost-behavior for an article about how the AI in the original Pac-Man actually worked.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström I understand what I need to do just not how to. I don't understand how I should get the distances of all valid paths to a target point. Once I know which way takes the least amount the decision part is easy but I just don't know how to at a intersection choose the shortest path.

Comment: @Fogest: The article isn't about what, but about how. The original AI didn't work anything like that. It didn't try to find the shortest path. Not that it matters, you're free to do it however you like, just thought you would find the article interesting.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström Yeah I guess your right it just checked the spots that were free in each direction except behind and then checked which spots was directly longer and it didn't actually count that distance if the ghost were to go on the path. This does make it a lot easier. Based on how much time I have left to finish this I think checking the direct distance will be less time consuming and therefore a better choice  even if less "smart"

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström I guess even if it's not as ideal to go a certain way because it could be longer, it would also that the Ghost would sometimes look smarter because it may be going a direction that would be cutting the Ghost off.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström The only thing that I may have problems with is what happens when pacman's direction and pacman is facing a wall on the border? For the Blue ghost is takes spot two places infront and gets vector for Red ghost to PAcman and doubles it. Therefore it would be pretty far distance from the game. I'm guessing this is okay since pacman's direction should change soon anyway so it won't be obvious.

Comment: Crop it at the edge i guess. By the way, do you realize the board is rotated 90 degrees?

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström Yes I do. It was a mistake in the way I did the array. It's not that big of a deal because the goal of this school project was not to make a exact Pacman it was to simply make a game.

Comment: Actually, the array looks right, but the game board rotated. Just switch the loop variables reading from the array... :)

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström Last time I did that it was messed up. I forget what but something was wrong and that was why I switched it.

Comment: Also, next time you're putting a map in source code, put it in strings to make it easier to read.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström that is harder to do though for a noob isn't it? I was familiar with the int array so I used it.

Comment: Not really harder. Instead of using `board[y][x]` you use `board[y].charAt(x)`, and assign chars instead of numbers for different things, for example `"#...###...@...###...#"` where `#` is a wall, `.` is a dot, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a precomputed inkblot.  The "home" squares are labelled zero. Then, all unassigned neighbour squares of a square labelled n are assigned label n +1. Now all your "dead" ghosts have to do is move to a neighbouring square with a lower label. Eventually they will get home having taken the shortest path.  Easy!

Comment: So your saying basically each square out in a direction would be assigned n+1 each time out?

Comment: That is Dijkstra, and as alf said it's quite suitable for this problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm

Comment: It's a significant simplification of Dijkstra since you can't find a shorter path in this case by taking more steps.

Comment: Fogest, you only need compute the inkblot once since it never changes.

Comment: @Rafe Sorry I don't understand what you mean by compute the inkblot. I understand the concept of what needs to be done but implantation is difficult for a person of my skill level.

Comment: Fogest: He's saying that you should put a number on each square that says how many steps there are from that square to home. That way the ghost just has to move to the square with the lower number.

Answer (score 2):

You can look into [Lee's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee_algorithm) for shortest path inside a matrix with obstacles.

Comment: I am pretty new to programming and have not used or learnt about algorithms yet so it's easier said then done.

Comment: @Fogest: you will need some algorithmic tricks to solve this one. I can recommend the book [*AIMA](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/), first few chapters, for the basics of path searching.